# How to properly implement Windows Authentication in an ASP.NET Core app with Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular13, asp.net-core-6.0

I just finished creating an ASP.NET Core app with Angular as described in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022) tutorial.
When creating the ASP.NET Core project, I checked the option to enable Windows Authentication. As long as I add `[AllowAnonymous]` to my controllers in the ASP.NET Core project, everything already works just fine, but as soon as I replace that with `[Authorize]`, the requests from my Angular app no longer reach my code in the backend. Instead, the webserver returns a `400 Bad Request` error. Here is a request including the response headers where this problem occurs:
[image: Example 400 Bad Request]

After doing some research on my own, I found out that I probably need to enable CORS in the backend, since I am using a proxy via `proxy.conf.json` in the Angular app during development. Here is the content of the `proxy.conf.json`:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:7139",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Therefore, I tried to add `UseCors()` in my `Program.cs` of the ASP.NET Core project. Here is how the `Program.cs` currently looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(setup =>
{
    setup.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to make any difference. This is how my http GET call is implemented in the frontend:

```
this.http.get<string>(`api/test/1`, { responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true } as Record<string, unknown>).subscribe(value => {
      alert(value);
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

I feel like I am missing something important which I need to make Windows Authentication work here, but I don't know what exactly I am doing wrong. I do not even get any additional information from the webserver about why it even returns `400 Bad Request` here, so I don't know where to start debugging this issue.

UPDATE: I figured out how to enable more Kestrel-Logging by adding the following configuration-entries in the `Logging` section of my `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
"Default": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadRequests": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http2": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Http3": "Debug"
```

Here is what Kestrel is logging while handling the request which ends with a `400 Bad Request` error:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[39]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68N" accepted.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[1]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68N" started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[3]
      Connection 0HMGSHHNJQ68N established using the following protocol: Tls12
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7139/api/test/1 - -
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[0]
      Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1001]
      1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/api/test/1'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1005]
      Endpoint 'WebApp.Controllers.TestController.Get (WebApp)' with route pattern 'api/Test/{id}' is valid for the request path '/api/test/1'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[1]
      Request matched endpoint 'WebApp.Controllers.TestController.Get (WebApp)'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was not authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[6]
      Challenged 401 Negotiate.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was challenged.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68N" received FIN.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7139/api/test/1 - - - 401 0 - 189.6680ms
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68N" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[10]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68N" disconnecting.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68N" stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[39]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68O" accepted.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[1]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68O" started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[3]
      Connection 0HMGSHHNJQ68O established using the following protocol: Tls12
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7139/api/test/1 - -
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1001]
      1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/api/test/1'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1005]
      Endpoint 'WebApp.Controllers.TestController.Get (WebApp)' with route pattern 'api/Test/{id}' is valid for the request path '/api/test/1'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[1]
      Request matched endpoint 'WebApp.Controllers.TestController.Get (WebApp)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[1]
      Incomplete Negotiate handshake, sending an additional 401 Negotiate challenge.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7139/api/test/1 - - - 401 0 - 68.9309ms
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68O" received FIN.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[10]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68O" disconnecting.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68O" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[39]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68P" accepted.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[1]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68P" started.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68O" stopped.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[3]
      Connection 0HMGSHHNJQ68P established using the following protocol: Tls12
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7139/api/test/1 - -
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1001]
      1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/api/test/1'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1005]
      Endpoint 'WebApp.Controllers.TestController.Get (WebApp)' with route pattern 'api/Test/{id}' is valid for the request path '/api/test/1'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[1]
      Request matched endpoint 'WebApp.Controllers.TestController.Get (WebApp)'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[11]
      Negotiate error code: ClientError.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[10]
      The users authentication request was invalid.
      System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090308): Das Token, das der Funktion übergeben wurde, ist ungültig.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7139/api/test/1 - - - 400 0 - 40.9717ms
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[6]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68P" received FIN.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[10]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68P" disconnecting.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets[7]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68P" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Connections[2]
      Connection id "0HMGSHHNJQ68P" stopped.
```

The first connection (0HMGSHHNJQ68N ) seems to be where I initially get the login-dialog in my browser where I enter my AD credentials. The other connections are then logged when I hit OK after entering my credentials. Sadly, I can't really figure out how to solve the problem based on those logs, but I am quite sure that the credentials are not provided correctly from the Angular app.

What am I doing wrong and/or how can I figure out the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Instead of using the webpack proxy, can you try to access the API directly? Can you show your proxy.conf.js? Also, this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64862939/642579

Comment: @Markus Yes, trying to access the API directly works fine. For example, I can just access it directly in my browser via the URL `https://localhost:7139/api/test/1`, enter my AD credentials and it works just fine. Therefore, I think that the Angular app does not yet know how to deal with the credentials, but I have no clue how to configure it to do that. I also figured out how to get more useful logging out of Kestrel. I added the logs and the content of my `proxy.conf.json` to my question above. Do you have an idea how I can make this work?

Comment: In our case, we didn't use the proxy - that worked just fine. What happens if you change the request in Angular to `this.http.get<string>('https://localhost:7139/api/test/1', ...`?

Comment: @Markus When I try that I get the following error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7139/api/test/1' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Hi @Chris, it should be `builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200")` instead of `builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CORS configuration, you try to open the API in a very broad way. Unfortunately, when dealing with requests containing an AUTHORIZATION header, you cannot use "*" to allow all hosts, but you need to specify the hosts. Also, you need to call `AllowCredentials` to accept requests with credentials:

```
services.AddCors(setup =>
{
  setup.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
  {
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
      .AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowCredentials();
  });
});
```

Usually, the API is hosted under the same origin as the SPA in production, so  these settings can be omitted in environments other than dev. Also, you might want to add a configuration setting instead of hard-coding `http://localhost:4200`.

Comment: Do I still need the `UseCors()` call here, or is that unnecessary when using your code?

Comment: Yes, you still need `UseCors`.

Comment: Without a policy name (so just `app.UseCors()`)?

Comment: Yes, just `app.UseCors();`. The sample sets the default policy, so I don't think you have to specify a policy. At least it works like this in our app.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that but unfortunately I am still getting a `400 Bad Request` error with my example GET call. If I would get more details about the error I would at least have a starting point for debugging the problem, but right now I am just clueless.

Comment: You could try to move `AddControllers` after `AddAuthentication` and `AddAuthorization`.

Comment: Sadly, that also does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243825/discussion-between-markus-and-chris).

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the help! I accepted your answer despite the actual solution being in the chat and not in the answer itself. If anyone here encounters a similar problem like I did, please check out the chat discussion for more information on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The problem is with the SPA proxy not passing `www-authenticate` header.

I solved with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64863390/12094844

Comment: This is a key part of making windows auth work with Angular. Yet I have not found it anywhere except here.